# Visual studio bug with StreamWriter or my misunderstanding?

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

I have to work with some files containing Cyrillic text and I am using `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

However, there is some ridiculous problem (or my misunderstanding). The following constructor works just fine:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(someFile, Encoding.Default)){
}
```

Yet, when I try the following:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(someOtherfile, Encoding.Default)){
}
```

I get a compile-time error for an ivalid constructor. Yet, the following is in the specification at MSDN:

```
public StreamWriter(Stream stream, Encoding encoding);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure that *someOtherfile* is a stream too or a type convertable to stream?

Comment: Yes, this happens everytime I try it, even when, after closing the file/stream I have just opened with StreamReader, I try to open it with StreamWriter.

Comment: @JohnSmith post the code where you declare and modify `somefile` and `someotherfile`.

Comment: @JohnSmith: You haven't answered Tigran's question about the type of `someOtherFile`. It would really help if you could produce a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: So, what is the actual error you get. If you were calling an invalid ctor the code would not compile. Is the `Stream` writable? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.streamwriter.aspx

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the differences between the [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) and [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) you'll see that while [there *is* a constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8xxf0x5.aspx) of:

```
StreamReader(string, Encoding)
```

there *isn't* a constructor of

```
StreamWriter(string, Encoding)
```

My guess is that the type of `someFile` and `someOtherFile` is `string`, not `Stream`.

I would *also* advise you not to use `Encoding.Default` unless you're really, really sure that you want the platform-specific default encoding, which may well not handle all of Unicode. If you possibly can, use UTF-8 instead.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it using the public StreamWriter(string path, bool append, Encoding encoding); constructor.